# How to find out if a certain item from the dataset (ArrayList<obj>) is currently on the screen (RecyclerView)?

Tags: android, android-layout, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

Here is the problem: I have a dataset: `ArrayList<Alarm> alarms`, which is used by a RecyclerView to display rows. How to figure out if a certain item from the dataset is currently on the screen? Something, like

`boolean bl = recyclerView.isItemOnScreenNow(alarms.get(index));`

I know that there is a method `((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();`
but as far as I know it returns the position in the LayoutManager, not the position of the item in the dataset. So is there a way to find out if the certain member from the dataset is currently on the screen?
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done that way:

```
         BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                int indexToDelete = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                int idToDelete = intent.getIntExtra("Time to delete", 0);
                int idToDeleteOnScreen = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
           

                for(Iterator<Alarm> iterator = alarms.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
                    Alarm alarm = iterator.next();
                    if(alarm.getId() == idToDelete){
                       indexToDelete = alarms.indexOf(alarm);
                       break;
                    }
                }
               

                int index = 0;
                View view;
                while((view = recyclerView.getChildAt(index)) != null){
                    DisturberAdapter.AlarmHolder alarmHolder = (DisturberAdapter.AlarmHolder) recyclerView.getChildViewHolder(view);
                    int itemOnScreenId = alarmHolder.getId();
                    if(idToDelete == itemOnScreenId){
                        idToDeleteOnScreen = index;
                        Log.d("Dnd expireReceiver", "found! "+index);
                        break;
                    }
                   
                    index++;
                }
                if(view == null){
                        //If the item isn't on the screen, no need for animation, just delete
                    alarms.remove(indexToDelete);
                    recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else{
                        //If the view is on the screen start animation
                    animationRecyclerViewItemExpired(idToDeleteOnScreen, indexToDelete);
                }
   

            }
        };
```